# asciidoctor-maven-plugin generate pdf - unexpected kDO_BLOCK

Tags: maven, spring-boot, asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I am trying to generate pdf, using this tutorial:
https://www.baeldung.com/asciidoctor
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/asciidoctor/pom.xml

My pom looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>pl.a.s.f.b</groupId>
        <artifactId>b</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.SR2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SECURITY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.faljse</groupId>
            <artifactId>SDNotify</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-beta.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctorj</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>true</executable>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-info</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
                        <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${swagger-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <apiSources>
                                <apiSource>
                                    <springmvc>true</springmvc>
                                    <locations>
                                        <location>pl.a.s.f.b.gateway</location>
                                    </locations>
                                    <info>
                                        <title>Gateway api documentation</title>
                                        <version>v1</version>
                                    </info>
                                    <swaggerDirectory>${project.build.directory}/swagger</swaggerDirectory>
                                    <attachSwaggerArtifact>true</attachSwaggerArtifact>
                                </apiSource>
                            </apiSources>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.github.swagger2markup</groupId>
                        <artifactId>swagger2markup-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${swagger2markup-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <swaggerInput>${project.build.directory}/swagger/swagger.json</swaggerInput>
                            <outputDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/asciidoc</outputDir>
                            <config>
                                <swagger2markup.markupLanguage>ASCIIDOC</swagger2markup.markupLanguage>
                                <swagger2markup.generatedExamplesEnabled>true</swagger2markup.generatedExamplesEnabled>
                                <swagger2markup.interDocumentCrossReferencesEnabled>true
                                </swagger2markup.interDocumentCrossReferencesEnabled>
                            </config>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${asciidoctor-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                                <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
                                <version>1.5.0-alpha.18</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>output-pdf</id>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>pdf</backend>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>



    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jcenter-snapshots</id>
            <name>jcenter</name>
            <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>jcenter-releases</id>
            <name>jcenter</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

While executing

```
mvn  asciidoctor:process-asciidoc
```

I get following error

```
 Execution default-cli of goal org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-maven-plugin:1.5.6:process-asciidoc failed: 
(SyntaxError) C:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/asciidoctor/asciidoctorj-pdf/1.5.0-alpha.18/asciidoctorj-pdf-1.5.0-alpha.18.jar!/gems/asciidoctor-pdf-1.5.0.alpha.18/lib/asciidoctor-pdf/core_ext/numeric.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected kDO_BLOCK
[ERROR] Float.prepend (Module.new do
```

Adoc file content that i am trying to convert to pdf (i made it easier to show MVCE):

```
[[_paths]]
== Paths
```

I am wondering how can i successfully generate pdf?
I've managed to successfully generate html only - changing pom a little.

Answer (score 0):

The version should be the same, for example:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
        <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-alpha.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
        <artifactId>asciidoctorj</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-alpha.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

And in the plugin

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
      <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${asciidoctor-maven-plugin.version}</version>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
              <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
              <version>1.5.0-alpha.15</version>
          </dependency>
```